# How to keep magento migration syncronized until DNS update

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.6

I'm migrating my magento install from my current hosting to a VPS.
Of course this takes a while since I'm also adding some new features and I'm setting up the server. Each day we're adding new manufacturers and products, resulting in the copy on the new server always outdated (without products). I cannot download/override the whole Magento since it would reset all my changes...

I'm dumping the db with a cron task to keep it syncronized, but it doesn't export the images for the products... How can I perform a complete syncronization between this two installations?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to have both of your magento sites use the same database.  When you're done moving all your files and done updating, then just move the entire DB over to your VPS along with your product images.  This way you don't have to update both places or worry about synchronization.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. What directory should I move to have product images on the new VPS?

Comment: try MagentoRoot/app/media/catalog/product/